# Removing duplicates according to some columns and remaining them if the data from the last column is different

Tags: r, dataframe

```
cars <- data.frame(vehicle_type = c('OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 
                        ccm','OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 ccm','OCTAVIA 
                        2.0 TDI 110kW Style, liftback, 1 968 ccm','OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI CR DPF 
                         Ambition, hatchback, 1 598 ccm', 'OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 ccm'),
                    year_of_manufacture = c(1999, 1999, 1978, 1965, 1999),
                    price_total = c(189000, 189000, 235000, 123000, 189000),
                    time_stamp = c('11.03.2003', '11.03.2003', '19.08.1989', '10.06.1999'))
```

My task is to get rid of duplicates from my data frame but remain them if the data from the last column is different. How to do that?

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output for this sample input? Also, please make sure you post valid code. Right now the values in `time_stamp` aren't valid. Numbers can't have multiple decimal places in R. Maybe those are supposed to be strings.

Comment: My code should return a data frame without duplicated values 'OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 ccm' - 1999 - 189000 - '11.03.2003'. My task is to get rid of duplicated values according to the first 4 rows but remain some of them if the values in the last row is different but the same in the first 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

It removes the second (duplicate) row of the five. The fifth row is retained because of the differing time-stamp (which I added).

The vehicle types are cleaned up first as they have varying amounts of spacing; I assume you want to treat them as being the same?

(Note your sample data is missing the last time-stamp.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

cars <- data.frame(vehicle_type = c('OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 
                        ccm','OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 ccm','OCTAVIA 
                        2.0 TDI 110kW Style, liftback, 1 968 ccm','OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI CR DPF 
                         Ambition, hatchback, 1 598 ccm', 'OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 ccm'),
                   year_of_manufacture = c(1999, 1999, 1978, 1965, 1999),
                   price_total = c(189000, 189000, 235000, 123000, 189000),
                   time_stamp = c('11.03.2003', '11.03.2003', '19.08.1989', '10.06.1999', '11.07.1999'))

# Cleaned with duplicates removed
cars |> 
  mutate(vehicle_type = str_squish(vehicle_type)) |> 
  distinct()
#>                                            vehicle_type year_of_manufacture
#> 1 OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 ccm                1999
#> 2      OCTAVIA 2.0 TDI 110kW Style, liftback, 1 968 ccm                1978
#> 3 OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI CR DPF Ambition, hatchback, 1 598 ccm                1965
#> 4 OCTAVIA 1.6 TDI 66kW Ambition Combi, kombi, 1 598 ccm                1999
#>   price_total time_stamp
#> 1      189000 11.03.2003
#> 2      235000 19.08.1989
#> 3      123000 10.06.1999
#> 4      189000 11.07.1999
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>